# CentOS: How to keep previous service state on reboot

Tags: centos, service, centos9

Is there `unit` setting I can change so a service will stay stopped after reboot if it was stopped before reboot?

*Currently service starts with OS startup even if it was stopped*

CentOS9

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl disable --now whatever.service
```

Will remove the unit from targets, preventing start at boot.  `--now` will also stop it.

Default enabled state of a unit can be set in a couple ways. By administrator or distro policy, see `systemd.preset` Or, by editing the unit (`systemctl edit whatever.service`) and changing the Install section.

Comment: This will however always prevent the start, regardless of the state prior to the boot.

Comment: I cant find anything relevant on `install` section. all the copy-pasted *blogs* just use WantedBy and may be CreatedBy without much of explanation. So how do I change install section?